# Why do I not need to wrap this async result in a Task?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I have the following async method:

```
public async Task<Result> Create(ModelStateDictionary modelState, TCreateViewModel postedModel)
{
    var result = new Result();
    if (! modelState.IsValid)
    {
        result.CopyErrorsFromModelState(modelState);
        return result;
    }

    // never reached if modelState is invalid
    var attemptCreateResult = await AttemptCreate(dataModel);
    result.MergeResult(attemptCreateResult);

    return result;
}
```

Say I changed it to the below.  (I know it's kind of silly, but it's just to demonstrate.)

```
public async Task<Result> Create(ModelStateDictionary modelState, TCreateViewModel postedModel)
{
    var result = new Result();
    if (! modelState.IsValid)
    {
        result.CopyErrorsFromModelState(modelState);
    }

    return await Task.FromResult(result);
}
```

If `ModelState` is not valid, it would follow the exact same code path.

Yet on the first, I can return the `result` directly.  And in the second I would be required to wrap my return `result` in `Task.FromResult()`.

Can somebody explain to me why this is?

---

NOTE: I've really struggled to make this question clear, and not sure I've succeeded. I'd welcome any edits to clarify it. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await?rq=1

Comment: the second snippet is technically not async and can actually be removed. `return Task.FromResult(result);`. You are tryign to await an already completed Task in the second one. In the first one a state machine is created because of the proper use of async await.

Comment: Yeah, I know the second example is a bit dumb. But in the first example, if ModelState is not valid, the await operator contained within would never get hit. And I think that it would be the equivalent of the second.

Comment: no it wont. just because it does not reach the await does not make it the same as the second.

Comment: So the await (even if not hit) makes a difference in how the compiler runs the method?

Comment: Yes it does make a difference.

Comment: Ok, thanks. If you want to post as an answer I can mark it.

Comment: In both methods you can call `return result;` How do you conclude "in the second I would be required to wrap my return result in Task.FromResult()." ? The compiler automatically wraps the result into a task for you because the method is marked async.

Comment: It gave me a warning because the async method lacked await operators.